# Como pegar o ID de um objeto com Django?

Tags: html, python, django, button

Como pegar o ID de um objeto que está sendo exibido em uma página HTML com Django??

```
<div class="modal fade" data-modal-id="{{ vaga.nome_vaga }} @ {{ vaga.nome_empresa }}" tabindex="-1" {#aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" #}aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog{# modal-lg#}">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title h5 titulovaga" id="modalVaga">{{ vaga.nome_vaga }} ({{ vaga.tipo_trabalho }})</h4>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <ul class="hide-bullets">
          <li>
            <ul class="inline-list">
              <li class="info" id="nomeEmpresa"><i class="bi bi-building" title="Empresa"></i> {{ vaga.nome_empresa }}</li>
              <li class="info" id="localEmpresa"><i class="bi bi-geo-alt" title="Local"></i> {{ vaga.local_empresa }}</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <ul class="inline-list">
              <li class="info" id="tipoDeContrato"><i class="bi bi-file-earmark-text" title="Tipo de contrato"></i> {{ vaga.tipo_contratacao }}</li>
              <li class="info" id="perfilProfissional"><i class="bi bi-person-workspace" title="Perfil profissional"></i> {{ vaga.perfil_profissional }}</li>
              <li class="info" id="salario">R$ {{ vaga.salario }}</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <h5 class="subtituloVaga">Principais atividades</h5>
        <p>{{ vaga.principais_atividades }}</p>
        <h5 class="subtituloVaga">Requísitos</h5>
        <p>{{ vaga.requisitos }}</p>
        <h5 class="subtituloVaga">Diferencial</h5>
        <p>{{ vaga.diferencial }}</p>
        <h5 class="subtituloVaga">Descrição da vaga</h5>
        <p>{{ vaga.descricao_vaga }}</p>
        <h5 class="subtituloVaga">Descrição da empressa</h5>
        <p>{{ vaga.descricao_empresa }}</p>
        <h5 class="subtituloVaga">Area atuacao</h5>
        <p>{{ vaga.area_atuacao }}</p>
        <h5 class="subtituloVaga">Beneficios</h5>
        <p>{{ vaga.beneficios }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
        <div>
          <button type="button" class="" title="Favoritar"><i class="bi bi-star"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Candidatar-se</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

quero que este butão `<button type="button" class="" title="Favoritar"><i class="bi bi-star"></i></button>` possa passar para a minha views.py o id do objeto vaga que está sendo exibido

Answer (score 0):

Precisaria de mais alguns detalhes para uma resposta mais precisa, no entanto, supondo que o trecho de código da pergunta está dentro de um `<form method="post">` e que a ação de *Candidatar-se* já esteja sendo tratada em uma view específica, uma opção seria definir os atributos `name` e `value` para os botões *Favoritar* e *Candidatar-se*. Deste modo, o botão de favoritar ficaria como no exemplo a seguir:

```
<button type="button" name="action" value="favoritar" class="" title="Favoritar"><i class="bi bi-star"></i></button>
```

De modo semelhante, o botão de candidatar-se teria os atributos `name="action"` e `value="candidatar"`.

Assim, na mesma view onde será tratada a ação de candidatar-se, pode ser tratada a ação de favoritar. Exemplo:

```
def tratar_vaga(request, pk):       
    vaga = Vaga.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.POST
        action = data.get("action")
        if action == "favoritar":
            bla bla bla
        elif action == "candidatar":
            bla bla bla
    return render(...)
```

Note que a view já recebe o id da vaga (`pk`), supondo que você já tenha essa construção definida para tratar a opção de *candidatar-se*.